# Historic vs Historical

Tags: word-usage

I'm a bit confused with the meme "I'm tired of living through these historical events" referring to the traumatic experience living during a pandemic. Isn't it supposed to be "historic"?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: ***Historic or historical?*** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/historic-or-historical - https://www.grammarly.com/blog/historic-historical/